# Undefined symbol '_getline' in module in C

Tags: c, linker

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 100

/* rudimentary calculator */
main() {
  double sum, atof(char []);
  char line[MAXLINE];
  int getline(char line[], int max);

  sum = 0;
  while(getline(line, MAXLINE) > 0)
      printf("\t%g\n", sum += atof(line));
  return 0;
}
```

I am learning to code in C from the Ritchie & Kernighan C Programming manual.

I'm using the borland turbo c compiler.

The code is for making a rudimentary calculator.

I'm getting a  **Linker Error: Undefined symbol '_getline' in module**

Comment: And where is the `getline` function defined (implemented)?

Comment: This was the code in the tutorial book. So I tried it but got the getline undefined error.

Comment: How do I define getline() in the code?

Comment: The book doesn't show its implementation? I think it should, somewhere.

Comment: Another problem is that `getline` is a non-standard function that some non-conforming compilers like to spew out inside standard headers. Turbo C was a bit shaky with standard compliance, though far better than other year 1989 compilers. Is this for your computer archaeology class?

Comment: @Lundin No, I'm using a Windows 7 32-bit Starter Edition

Comment: @sagar_02 Hmmm, Maybe you overlooked that the definition of `getline` was in previous examples in the book. For me this seems the most matching reason. I can't think of that they forgot to implement a definition nor that they declare the `getline()` function a second time.

Comment: BTW Could you cite the exact page? We/I can take a look at that ourself/myself.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio The C Programming Language - Ritchie and Kernighan (page 62-63)

Comment: Why not use a sane, modern, free compiler like gcc with a free IDE like Codeblocks?

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a function definition for `getline()`.

There is only a function declaration/ prototype

```
int getline(char line[], int max);
```

in your program for `getline()`, but no function definition.

---

Regarding your issue with K&R, you missed the following from the previous Chapter 4.1 "Basics of Functions" short before the exercise with the rudimentary calculator:

> "The mechanics of how to compile and load a C program that resides on multiple source files vary from one system to the next. On the UNIX system, for example, the cc command mentioned in Chapter 1 does the job. Suppose that the three functions are stored in three files called main.c, getline.c, and strindex.c. Then the command
>
> `cc main.c getline.c str index.c`
>
> compiles the three files... "
>
> Source: The C Programming Language (1. version), Page 61

as well as

> "There is also a slightly different version of getline; you might find it instructive to compare it to the one in Chapter 1"
>
> Source: The C Programming Language (1. version), Page 60

```
int getline (char s[], int lim)   
{       
    int c, i;       
    i = 0;       

    while (--lim > 0 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')           
       s[i++] = c;       

    if (c == '\n')           
       s[i++] = c;       

    s[i] = '\0';       

    return i;   
}
```

The example requires either,

1. That you link `getline.c` (with the function definition of `getline()`) from Chapter 1 at the compiler invocation, or
2. That you use the different definition of `getline()` in one of the program examples (Page 60) before.

---

Side notes:

- Please switch to an up-to-date and standard-compliant compiler like gcc with [MingW](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) for Windows, if you aren't forced to do different for a class.

  Turbo C is very old and I think it wasn't even compliant to ANSI C (C89/C90).
- I have been looking in the "Second Edition" of the "The C Programming Language" first and couldn't found your cited example at Page 61-62.

  Please consider to get a copy of the Second Edition of the book. It is compliant to ANSI C and contains important updates.

  You can get a PDF of it, [here](http://kremlin.cc/k&r.pdf).
- Regarding point 1 and point 2, `main()` is also no longer compliant to actual C standards. It shall be `int main (void)`.
- Note that there is a POSIX function with the same name `getline()` available under some implementations. You can get an error if this function is included in your implementation (but it seems it isn't) since both  functions (the POSIX and the K&R one) have different prototypes and you would attempt to redefine the POSIX `getline()` function then.

Comment: Thanks!, currently trying to implement your instructions. Will get back to you if it works for me.

Comment: @sagar_02 The simplest way, I guess, is to just include the definition of `getline()` I provided in the answer into the .c file.

Comment: Okay, actually,  just found out I am in fact using the second edition of K & R , and not the first one.

Comment: @sagar_02 But in the second edition the rudimentary calculator is at page 72, not 62/63. I think you are using the first edition.

Comment: @sagar_02 Just take a look at the link I provided. There you can find a copy of the second edition. If it doesn't match, you have the first edition.